java, springboot, webflux connectionRefused WebClientRequestException
I am developing a spring boot microservice using web flux to perform some queries. And then I want to test the functionality of my controllers using WebClient, but I'm getting the exception below:
enter image description here
I don't understand what the problem is. Application starts successfully. Can anyone help me please to solve this problem
Here webclient configuration in app:
enter image description here
And usage of it in app:
enter image description here
Code of fallen test:
enter image description here
Also i watch host on which port 8080 is listening and it was localhost
